# Why am I getting empty array in fetch request to MongoDB from ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to fetch all the articles from a document in MongoDB in React. It is perfectly working in Backend with NodeJS when I tested with Postman. But in Frontend , React, I am getting empty array. How to solve this.

## Server.js (Backend)

```
app.get('/api/articles', async (req, res)=>{
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
    const db = client.db('my-blog')

    const articleInfo= await db.collection('articles').find({}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err)
        res.status(200).send(result)
        client.close()
    })
    
})
```

## articlePage.js (FrontEnd)

```
componentDidMount(){
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        };
        const fetchdata = fetch('/api/articles/').then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({articles:data}))
        console.log(this.state.articles)

    }
```

Api address is set up in package.json with `proxy:http://localhost:8000`

How to get the documents data from MongoDB in React?

Comment: Your console log is going to show the old state. State doesn't change until the next render.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check if you the API call went through to the server from your React app. If it has, then check for the response code in the network. In your case, 200 is where you get the desired result from the API. If you are not getting the desired result, then check your collection and document names and also arguments your are passing in the query.

Answer (score 0):

As `setState` is not synchronized, you have to access it in the callback.

```
this.setState({ articles: data }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.articles)
})
```